# Location Not Displayed When Using Geo location in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I'm developing a Phone Gap application. In that application I Want to show the current user's position. For that I used HTML5 geolocation. When I click on the Get Location button it doesn't display a location. It also doesn't display an error. After pressing the Get Location button it simply shows the button in the selected state.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <button onclick="getLocation()">Get Location</button>
    <script>
        var x = document.getElementById("demo");
        function getLocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
            }
            else { x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser."; }
        }
        function showPosition(position) {
            x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
        }
        function showError(error) {
            switch (error.code) {
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                    x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
                    break;
                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                    x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
                    break;
                case error.TIMEOUT:
                    x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
                    break;
                case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                    x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
                    break;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing an element that doesn't exist.
Add a div to your html body with id="demo", like so:

```
<div id="demo"></div>
```

See it here on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wU6AE/